# I have two json data object andf if I click on name it go to the details of that name and same for other names as well

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I have two json data object and it create two name tile from data.now when I click on that name it go to detaile of that name and populate details from that json data and it dose some for other name as well

javascript code.

```
var data =[ {
  "id" : 1051,
 "datasetName" : "Work Order",
 "source" : "Passport",
 "business" : "Generation",
 "subBusiness" : "Utility",
"entityDescription" : null,
"lastRefreshed" : "2017-06-14",
"noOfRecords" : null,
"primaryKey" : null,
"createdBy" : "Admin",
"createdDate" : "2017-06-14",
"updatedBy" : "Admin",
"updatedDate" : "2017-06-14",
"restURL" : "https://exdatacat.predix.io",
"accesstoken" : "jhjhjhjhjhjh-akjaksjas",
"filterCond" : null,
"dataStartdt" : null,
"dataEnddt" : null,
"refreshFrequency" : null,
 "predixOrgName" : null,
 "predixSpaceName" : null,
  "predixDBName" : null,
   "predixTableName" : "passport_work_order"
  },{
  "id" : 1051,
 "datasetName" : "Work Order",
 "source" : "Passport",
 "business" : "Generation",
 "subBusiness" : "Utility",
"entityDescription" : null,
"lastRefreshed" : "2017-06-14",
"noOfRecords" : null,
"primaryKey" : null,
"createdBy" : "Admin",
"createdDate" : "2017-06-14",
"updatedBy" : "Admin",
"updatedDate" : "2017-06-14",
"restURL" : "https://exdatacat.predix.io",
"accesstoken" : "jhjhjhjhjhjh-akjaksjas",
"filterCond" : null,
"dataStartdt" : null,
"dataEnddt" : null,
"refreshFrequency" : null,
 "predixOrgName" : null,
 "predixSpaceName" : null,
  "predixDBName" : null,
   "predixTableName" : "passport_work_order"
  }]

 $http.get(data).then(function(resp){
    var featuresData = resp.data;

angular.forEach(featuresData, function(value, key){

    if(value.id == "1051" )
    {
        $scope.featuresData = [value]
        return;

    }
    else if(value.id == "1052" )
    {
        $scope.featuresData = [value]

    }
    return [value];
});
})
  <div class="col-sm-12 passPortWorkDiv" ng-repeat="data in 
   featuresData">
    <div>{{data.datasetName}}</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You got me a little bit confused here..

Comment: when I have two object and when I click on name1 from first object it go to detile of that first object and when I click on name2 it go detaile of that second object and show on UI with detaile.  At this movement doesn't metter where I click it show detile of last object only.

Comment: You could use ng-click with a custom function that receives the current object's details and place them in a "currentDetails" variable.

Comment: I am already used

Comment: Ok, i'll try to bring a complete answer, just a moment.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to parse JSON data in a javascript script.

If so, try doing the following:

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
```

Then you can index that data for specific variables (`data.datasetName`)

You need to parse the JSON data into a Javascript object first, so that you can index it in your HTML code!

Hope this helps!

[Source - W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are always overwriting your array with a one-value array: `[value]`. Whatever you had before is being replaced.

Consider using `filter` instead of `forEach`:

```
$scope.featuresData = featuresData.filter(function(value) {
    return value.id == "1051" || value.id == "1052";
});
```

Comment: this is atually working but showing detaile of both object

Comment: Well your problem was that you only had the detail of the last object, so if you don't want the details of the other object, then what *do* you want? Your code mentioned two id values (1051, 1052). If you only want one of them, then don't mention the other.

Comment: I am getting two object but when i file one value it should show first object data and whn i click on second it show second icon data

Comment: But where is your click handler? What do you mean with "file one value"?

Answer (score 0):

Based in what you said before, i think this might help.

Your data source:

```
var data = [
    {
        "id": 1051,
        "datasetName": "Work Order",
        "source": "Passport",
        "business": "Generation",
        /* ... */
        "predixTableName": "passport_work_order"
    },
    {
        "id": 1051,
        "datasetName": "Work Order",
        "source": "Passport",
        "business": "Generation",
        /* ... */
        "predixTableName": "passport_work_order"
    }
]
```

Somewhere in your controller:

```
$http.get(data).then(function(resp){
    var featuresData = resp.data;
});

$scope.showDetails = function (data) {
    $scope.currentDetails = data;
};
```

In the HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 passPortWorkDiv" ng-repeat="data in featuresData">
    <a href="#" ng-click="showDetails(data)">{{data.datasetName}}</a>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 ng-show="currentDetails">
    <p>datasetName: {{currentDetails.datasetName}}</p>
    <p>business: {{currentDetails.business}}</p>
    <p>lastRefreshed: {{currentDetails.lastRefreshed}}</p>
    /* ... */
</div>
```